# Viewer node does not pop up in Blender 3.0

Tags: node-editor, shadows

I am close to  nervous breakdown.
I have tried everything but the viewer node does not show up.
I have rendered the image.
I have enabled the node Wranger add-on.
When I click Shift+Ctrl+LMB the output of the node just connects to Material output but the viewer node does not show up.
Would anyone have an idea ? [image]

Comment: Is there anything going on in your System Console while this is happening? Go to *Window> Toggle System Console* and then try it again. See if any Python Errors are popping up when trying to run the command.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion !! Unfortunately, nothing shows up!

Comment: Hmm, then can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: The viewer node won't appear if you just have the default Principled BSDF shader in the shader editor and Shift+Ctrl+LMB click on that. If you add (for instance) a Voronoi texture and Shift+Ctrl+LMB click on that, does the viewer node then appear?

Comment: Hey guys, you are the best, thank you very much !! Do not really know where the error came from..  Maybe from the fact that I use Anaconda a lot and it might have messed up with blender's python code ?? I reinstalled Blender and then it worked for Voronoi texture. Maybe its also just the fact that I was applying to the wrong nodes, even though I had tried it on a lot of nodes. Anyways, thank you so so so so much !! I can go on with my project. Have a wonderful day !!

Comment: It seems like you found the answer to this question via the comments or other sources. Please add it as an answer to the question itself, so it will show up as answered.